# How to convert a string containing a number into GB/s

Tags: c, linux

I wanted to convert a byte value into GB/s using C. For instance, value in bytes is "11,584,000,000".
Tried this convert it to MB/s using the following:

```
   (11,584,000,000 >> 20) to convert to MB/s .i.e 11047 MB/s
```

but as per an online calculator, it should be 11584 MB/S or 11.584 GB/s, what is the right to do it?

Comment: Technically `11047 MiB/s` ≅ `11584 MB/s`

Comment: If, instead of resorting to a trick with that `>>20` you had written the real operation you meant (`x / 1024 / 1024`), the problem would be obvious.

Comment: More info on it [SI & IEC - Binary Prefix - Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix)

Comment: One issue is getting a string with commas separating groups of 3 digits into a decimal number.  Another issue is scaling the result appropriately, probably using `double` values if the output should be 11.584 GB/s (or 11.047 GiB/s).  You also need to know how long it took to deliver those bytes — the implicit assumption is that they took 1 second.  To convert a value like that into a rate, you must know the time over which the volume was delivered

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of sizes.

[Gigabyte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabyte) (power of ten) and gibibyte (power of two).
You have created the power of two with the bit shift, which is also the technical size.

1000MB are 1GB but 1024MiB are 1GiB.

Disk drive (SSD) manufacturers like to quote GB because it makes their disks seem bigger.

Comment: Re “Disk drive (SSD) manufacturers like to quote GB because it makes their disks seem bigger”: Or because decimal terms and abbreviations are part of an international standard and hardware folks have always used them and the software folks with their powers of two came later.

Comment: @EricPostpischil neither is really true. One of the major reasons for using powers of 2 to count disk space comes from the chunking of disk into 512-byte clusters. That choice came from hardware manufacturers. And it makes it completely impossible to read or write 1000 bytes from a disk. In fact, "100MB disks" never existed, the closest you can get is 99,999,744 or 100,000,256 bytes.

Comment: @spectras: Very little comes naturally in power of ten units. Things are often advertised in sold in units of kilograms or cubic centimeters or other units even if an actual purchase is not a whole number of thousands of grams or whatever unit is used. It is merely a unit of measure, not a constraint on the amount that can be sold in one purchase. And getting within .003% of the stated quantity on any physical product (wood, peanut butter, gasoline, whatever) would be remarkable, so griping about a difference between 99,999,744 bytes and 100 MB is petty.

Comment: @spectras: How does the fact that disks are often organized into 512-byte blocks make it not true that there is an international standard about decimal terms and abbreviations? How does it make it not true that hardware folks have long used these terms and abbreviations, and that the software folks came later? The prefixes "k" and "M" had clear formal definitions, meaning 1,000, and 1,000,000, long before anybody started using them to mean 1,024 or 1,048,576.

Comment: In short: software came to use 1024 as a basis when measuring disk size, because hardware manufacturers made it mandatory when addressing their hardware. Hence *"software folks with their powers of two came later"* is misleading at best. It's not *"their powers of two"* and they didn't come later than manufacturer's. It remains that both came after the SI system for sure, but that has nothing to do with the relationship between software and manufacturer folks.